# Is block's timestamp current block's or previous block's timestamp?

Tags: solidity, blocks, block-header, timestamp

When I call function giveTime, is the time stamp "now" from the block where my call is mined or from the previous block?

```
contract Time {
  uint time;

  function giveTime() {
    time=now;
  }

  function Timestamp() constant returns (uint block_time) {
    block_time=time;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the timestamp of the current block.

The idea is like this: When a miner mines a block, he/she picks the timestamp, executes all contracts with the chosen timestamp to update the state, and does the searching. Thus, `now` is the timestamp of the current block.